# How can you stop vertical bounce when scrolling

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a problem with vertical bounce on a HTML page made for iOS. I have a landscape image which is scrollable but you can still move the image up and down. I would like the image to be locked from moving it up and down. I have tried:

Overflow: hidden;

and this stopped the vertical bounce but also stopped the ability to scroll on the y axis. Is there a way to lock the image vertically but still have the ability to scroll-y. Can this be achieved through using just HTML & CSS or will it involve using Javascript?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: auto;` is the property for which you are looking. Alternatively, `overflow-y: scroll;` might work, as well. The difference is that the former will only allow y-scrolling where necessary, whereas the latter will **always** place a y-scrollbar regardless of whether you can actually scroll or not.

More information available from **[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)**.

Comment: @user3437161 if my answer is correct, helpful, please mark it as such.